# How to create a multiple variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying calculate a, sort of, moving average for my data in SQL Server 2008, but the only way I have found is by using a @variable. For example I have this set of data:

```
StudyDate  Cpty Value
---------- ---- ----------------------
2015-11-24 1    3009
2015-11-24 2    2114
2015-11-24 3    558
2015-11-24 4    121
2015-11-24 5    2515
2015-11-24 6    81
2015-11-24 7    80
2015-11-24 8    1534
2015-11-24 9    136
2015-11-24 10   5674
2015-11-25 1    2731
2015-11-25 2    2197
2015-11-25 3    550
2015-11-25 4    124
2015-11-25 5    2532
2015-11-25 6    81
2015-11-25 7    80
2015-11-25 8    1700
2015-11-25 9    122
2015-11-25 10   5788
2015-11-26 1    2666
2015-11-26 2    2175
2015-11-26 3    408
2015-11-26 4    124
2015-11-26 5    2545
2015-11-26 6    81
2015-11-26 7    81
2015-11-26 8    1712
2015-11-26 9    122
2015-11-26 10   5967
```

And I want to find a moving average for every day. If I run this Query:

```
DECLARE @StudyDate DATE = '2015-11-26'
SELECT  @StudyDate,
        Cpty,
        AVG(Value)
FROM #MovAvg
WHERE StudyDate > DATEADD(m,-1,@StudyDate) AND StudyDate <= @StudyDate
GROUP BY Cpty
ORDER BY Cpty
```

Then I get the average for only one day '2015-11-26', but can I get an average for every day for every Cpty?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "moving average".  What is the window you care about?

Comment: `DATEADD(m,-1,@StudyDate)` will subtract one month off the date, not one day. In the query you posted it generates the average over the prior month for every counterparty...

Comment: The "moving average" here would be if my data exceeds 1 month of observations, then the average would be calculated based on the the last 30 Days of data.What I am looking for here

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The "moving average" here would be if my data exceeds 1 month of observations, then the average would be calculated based on the the last 30 Days of data.
What I am looking for here is how can I declare multiple variables under StudyDate? I know that with simple
`DECLARE @StudyDate DATE`
I can only use 1 variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you would do this using `outer apply`.  I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "moving average", but it appears to be the average for the previous month.

So:

```
select t.*, tavg.value
from t outer apply
     (select avg(t2.value) as value
      from t t2
      where t2.cpty = t.cpty and
            t2.studydate > DATEADD(month, -1, t.StudyDate) and
            t2.StudyDate <= t.StudyDate
     ) tavg;
```

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff! This actually helps!